# what is the likely cause of CMOS_WRITE failing to work?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, kernel-module

I've been puzzled by a RTC problem for several days: i couldn't write to the RTC register.

Following is the code snippet and the value I read from the reg(last line) is always different from what i just wrote to the reg. Anyone can help me understand this ?

```
    val = CMOS_READ(RTC_FREQ_SELECT);
    printk(KERN_INFO "reading val=%d from RTC_FREQ_SELECT.\n", val);
    val &= 0xf0;
    val |= 2;
    printk(KERN_INFO "writing val=%d to RTC_FREQ_SELECT.\n", val);
    CMOS_WRITE(val, RTC_FREQ_SELECT);
    printk(KERN_INFO "reading val=%d from RTC_FREQ_SELECT.\n", CMOS_READ(RTC_FREQ_SELECT));
```

I am using linux 2.6 kernel and the platforms i tried were PPC and x86.

**UPDATE:**  more code snippets per Amardeep's comment...

```
   /* disable periodic interrupts */
    tmp_control = CMOS_READ(RTC_CONTROL);
    tmp_control &= ~RTC_PIE;
    CMOS_WRITE(tmp_control, RTC_CONTROL);

    CMOS_READ(RTC_INTR_FLAGS);

    val = CMOS_READ(RTC_FREQ_SELECT);
    printk(KERN_INFO "reading val=%d from RTC_FREQ_SELECT.\n", val);

    val &= 0xf0;
    /* ...... */
    val |= 2;
    printk(KERN_INFO "writing val=%d to RTC_FREQ_SELECT.\n", val);

    CMOS_WRITE(val, RTC_FREQ_SELECT);
    printk(KERN_INFO "reading val=%d from RTC_FREQ_SELECT.\n", CMOS_READ(RTC_FREQ_SELECT));


    /* Enable periodic interrupts */
    tmp_control = CMOS_READ(RTC_CONTROL);
    tmp_control |= RTC_PIE;

    CMOS_WRITE(tmp_control, RTC_CONTROL);

    /* read the flags register to start interrupts */
    CMOS_READ(RTC_INTR_FLAGS);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the specific RTC chip?  Most RTC's, you have to flip a bit to "pause" it while you read/write its register banks, then "unpause" it when done.  Usually, you want to do this as fast as possible.

Did you also check the chip docs to make sure the specific register you're trying to write to is allowed to be written to?